# What is the correct usage of DSum with multiple variables?

Tags: vba

Using DSum() is a super idea. Thank you for this advice. However:

```
Private Sub BerekenVorigSaldo() Dim strFinInst As String Dim strPer As String

With Me
    strFinInst = .strIBAN
    strPer = .dteBoekdatum
End With

Tot = DSum("[SomVanBedrag]", "[sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo]", "[Boekdatum] <= " & strPer)
Tot = DSum("[SomVanBedrag]", "[sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo]", ("[Rekening] = " & "'" & strFinInst & "'"))
sngVorigSaldo = DSum("[SomVanBedrag]", "[sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo]", "[Boekdatum] <= " & strPer And "[Rekening] = '" & strFinInst & "'")
End Sub
```

When I separate the 2 conditions, I get (wrong) results and when I combine both conditions (as in the last line: sngVorigSaldo ...) I get an error message: Error 13 during execution, types do not match.

What am I typing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the field `[Boekdatum]` is a date, so you need to format the input as such. Also, the `AND` should be within the criteria string to merge the second condition.

In VBA you need to use `&` to concatenate the two strings.

Try this:

```
"[Boekdatum] <= " & Format(strPer,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " AND [Rekening] = '" & strFinInst & "'"
```